# How to combine and display records from 2 table with one query?

Tags: php, sql

currently working on a web project and i need help. how can i display values from 2 different tables in the database to a page? i'm still new in programming...
these are the 2 tables from database

### Table A

```
| NAME  |  AGE |   ID  |

  bryan    19     001
```

### Table B

```
| current balance | date balance updated  |

       200            january 22, 2015
```

...and i want all of these to display in my web(below):

```
| name:    |  bryan |

| age:     |   19   |

| id:      |  001   |

| balance: |  200   |
```

any help is appreciated, thanks...

Comment: you'll need to join the two tables

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't here to code problems for you, we're here to help you debug them. Please post what you have tried. If you haven't tried anything, that would be a good place to start.

Comment: You' need an ID in your second table that corresponds to the ID in the first table. After which a simple join on said ID should do the trick.

Comment: There must be something to link both tables..ID,Name,w/e you can't just go try to find who is whos.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Show us some code, some attempts of your own.'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As you show it, the table "B" does not have any column, that would tell us, who this balance belongs to. If you add such a field, we will be able to help you!

Comment: Looks like you could `JOIN` on the name field in each table. Give that a shot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First that you need to do is to add **foreign key** in the second table. You need a field that will be pointing to the ID field in the second table:

Table B:

```
| current balance | date balance updated  |  person_id

   200            january 22, 2015           001
```

Now you can select data from both tables using **LEFT JOIN** statement:

```
SELECT a.name, a.age, a.id, b.balance 
FROM table_a as a 
LEFT JOIN table_b as b ON b.person_id = a.id
```

**JOIN** is very powerful and frequently used construction. Learn more about it: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: thanks. i decided to drop all tables and make new one.


`CREATE TABLE users (
  name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  balance int(10) NOT NULL,
  id int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

and

`CREATE TABLE transactions (
id int(20) NOT NULL,
transaction_date datetime NOT NULL,
balance int NOT NULL,
order_id int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

but im now stuck with adding foreign key

`ALTER TABLE transactions
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES users(id)`

im getting an errno:150.
where did i do wrong?

Comment: You are trying to set foreign key for `id` field which is already used for primary key. You should create another field e.g. `user_id` and set foreign key for that field.